# Getters and Setters Through EventObject - ClassCastException Same Class (Java)

Tags: java, class, events, classcastexception

I'm trying to get and set values of a class through an EventObject, but when casting the `getSource()` to the proper class, I run into a ClassCastException with the same class. How can I get around this while being able to get and set values through the EventObject?

Thank you,
Hunter

ItemPanelEvent:

```
import java.util.EventObject;

public class ItemPanelEvent extends EventObject implements Items{

ItemPanel itemPanel;

public ItemPanelEvent(Object source) {
    super(source);
}

public ItemPanelEvent(Object source, int position) {
    super(source);
    itemPanel = (ItemPanel) getSource();
    itemPanel.setPosition(position);
}

public int getPosition() {
    itemPanel = (ItemPanel) getSource();
    return itemPanel.getPosition();
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    itemPanel = (ItemPanel) getSource();
    itemPanel.setPosition(position);
}

}
```

ItemPanel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ItemPanel extends JPanel implements Items{

private int position;

private String item;
private String buyPrice;
private String sellPrice;
private String quantity;
private String pcBuyPrice;
private String pcSellPrice;

private JLabel itemLabel;
private JLabel buyPriceLabel;
private JLabel sellPriceLabel;
private JLabel quantityLabel;
private JLabel pcBuyPriceLabel;
private JLabel pcSellPriceLabel;

private JLabel itemValue;
private JLabel buyPriceValue;
private JLabel sellPriceValue;
private JLabel quantityValue;
private JLabel pcBuyPriceValue;
private JLabel pcSellPriceValue;

private JButton logBtn;
private JButton editBtn;
private JButton cancelBtn;



private ItemPanelListener itemPanelListener;

public ItemPanel(int position, String item, String buyPrice, String sellPrice,
        String quantity, String pcBuyPrice, String pcSellPrice) {
    this.position = position;
    this.item = item;
    this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
    this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.pcBuyPrice = pcBuyPrice;
    this.pcSellPrice = pcSellPrice;

    Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
    dim.height = 100;
    setPreferredSize(dim);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));

    logBtn = new JButton("Log Item");
    editBtn = new JButton("Edit Item");
    cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel Item");


    setupLabels();
    setupCancelItemButton();

    layoutComponents();


}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int pos) {
    position = pos;
}

public void setupCancelItemButton() {
    cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ItemPanelEvent ev = new ItemPanelEvent(this);

            if (itemPanelListener != null) {
                itemPanelListener.itemPanelEventOccurred(ev);
            }

        }
    });
}

public void setItemPanelListener(ItemPanelListener listener) {
    this.itemPanelListener = listener;
}

public void setupLabels() {
    itemLabel = new JLabel("ITEM:");
    buyPriceLabel = new JLabel("BUY PRICE:");
    sellPriceLabel = new JLabel("SELL PRICE:");
    quantityLabel = new JLabel("QUANTITY:");
    pcBuyPriceLabel = new JLabel("PC BUY PRICE:");
    pcSellPriceLabel = new JLabel("PC SELL PRICE:");

    itemValue = new JLabel(this.item);
    buyPriceValue = new JLabel(this.buyPrice);
    sellPriceValue = new JLabel(this.sellPrice);
    quantityValue = new JLabel(this.quantity);
    pcBuyPriceValue = new JLabel(this.pcBuyPrice);
    pcSellPriceValue = new JLabel(this.pcSellPrice);
}

public void layoutComponents() {
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    // First Row
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(itemLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(itemValue, gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(buyPriceLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(buyPriceValue, gc);

    gc.gridx = 4;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(sellPriceLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 5;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(sellPriceValue, gc);

    gc.gridx = 6;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(quantityLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 7;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(quantityValue, gc);

    gc.gridx = 8;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(pcBuyPriceLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 9;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(pcBuyPriceValue, gc);

    gc.gridx = 10;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(pcSellPriceLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 11;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(pcSellPriceValue, gc);

    // Second Row
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;

    gc.gridx = 6;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(logBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 8;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(editBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 10;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    add(cancelBtn, gc);
}

}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't blindly case objects, use `instanceof` to test if the object is of the type you expecting before you cast it

Comment: Sorry @PaulBoddington, I have added a concise amount of code for the question. Thanks for the idea @MadProgrammer, but I know the source of the event has to be the ItemPanel, but I am unable to cast to it due to the ClassCastException Same Class Error. Testing with `instanceof` will show me I cannot cast the source and thus not accomplish the goal of modifying the values in the ItemPanel class.

Comment: This is the error I receive in the console in case it helps clarify the issue: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: ItemPanel$1 cannot be cast to ItemPanel
 at ItemPanelEvent.getPosition(ItemPanelEvent.java:18)
 at FlipPanel$1.itemPanelEventOccurred(FlipPanel.java:65)
 at ItemPanel$1.actionPerformed(ItemPanel.java:92)

Comment: @HunterCorry `ItemPanel$1` means an anonymous class inside `ItemPanel`, not `ItemPanel` itself. Can you post the full code for `ItemPanel`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I've updated my original post with the full code for `ItemPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemPanel$1` is the anonymous class implementing `ActionListener` that you create in the `setupCancelItemButton` method:

```
cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  // This creates a new class implementing ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ItemPanelEvent ev = new ItemPanelEvent(this);    // Here is the problem

        if (itemPanelListener != null) {
            itemPanelListener.itemPanelEventOccurred(ev);
        }

    }
});
```

When you write

```
ItemPanelEvent ev = new ItemPanelEvent(this);
```

`this` actually refers to the `ActionListener` *not* to the `ItemPanel`.

To correct your code you should write

```
ItemPanelEvent ev = new ItemPanelEvent(ItemPanel.this);
```

instead, and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @PaulBoddington